# How does sending MIDI over USB compare to using a dedicated MIDI interface?

Tags: midi, electronics

Is there an informed comparison between sending MIDI over USB versus directly from a MIDI interface on a PC expansion card - would a MIDI interface on a sound card provide some useful system enhancement over using a plain USB 2.0 connection (perhaps to a MIDI converter anyway)?

Answer (score 5):

It is better to use USB, it saves having to buy and power a MIDI interface and you avoid the extra latency that is built into an old school midi port (3 ms.) Also in a ping it's easier to find a USB cable than a MIDI cable.

Comment: Using the ASIO driver reduces USB latency to 0.73 ms